# Help with mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Need a little help getting the following rule working:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}            ^asset.*.domainone\.com [NC,AND]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}          !^/FILE/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              "http://domaintwo\.com/$1" [L]
```

For requests coming to this server with a domain of 'asset(anything).domain.com' which does not start with 'FILE', redirect to another server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^asset.*?\.domainone\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/FILE/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://domaintwo.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: With this set, if I navigate to asset1.domainone.com/whatever it does not redirect to domaintwo.

Comment: @Louis - I removed the backslash in the last line.

Comment: It still is NOT redirecting traffic to urls not starting with /FILE/